# PyTorch - RuntimeError: Sizes of tensors must match except in dimension 2. Got 55 and 54 (The offending index is 0)

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch, image-segmentation

I used a 3DUnet with resblock to segment a CT image with input torch size of [1, 1, 96, 176, 176], but it throws the following error:

*RuntimeError: Sizes of tensors must match except in dimension 2. Got 55 and 54 (The offending index is 0)*

Hence I traced back, I found the error comes from

```
outputs = self.decoder_stage2(torch.cat([short_range6, long_range3], dim=1)) + short_range6
```

The short_range6 has torch.Size([1, 64, 24, **55**, 40]) while the long_range3 has torch.Size([1, 128, 24, **54**, 40]). I think this is because something not being a power of 2, but cannot find where to modify.

Below is the complete structure of the network, really thanks for any help!

````
class ResUNet(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, in_channel=1, out_channel=2 ,training=True):
        super().__init__()

        self.training = training
        self.dorp_rate = 0.2

        self.encoder_stage1 = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Conv3d(in_channel, 16, 3, 1, padding=1),
            nn.PReLU(16),

            nn.Conv3d(16, 16, 3, 1, padding=1),
            nn.PReLU(16),
        )

        self.encoder_stage2 = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Conv3d(32, 32, 3, 1, padding=1),
            nn.PReLU(32),

            nn.Conv3d(32, 32, 3, 1, padding=1),
            nn.PReLU(32),

            nn.Conv3d(32, 32, 3, 1, padding=1),
            nn.PReLU(32),
        )

        self.encoder_stage3 = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Conv3d(64, 64, 3, 1, padding=1),
            nn.PReLU(64),

            nn.Conv3d(64, 64, 3, 1, padding=2, dilation=2),
            nn.PReLU(64),

            nn.Conv3d(64, 64, 3, 1, padding=4, dilation=4),
            nn.PReLU(64),
        )

        self.encoder_stage4 = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Conv3d(128, 128, 3, 1, padding=3, dilation=3),
            nn.PReLU(128),

            nn.Conv3d(128, 128, 3, 1, padding=4, dilation=4),
            nn.PReLU(128),

            nn.Conv3d(128, 128, 3, 1, padding=5, dilation=5),
            nn.PReLU(128),
        )

        self.decoder_stage1 = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Conv3d(128, 256, 3, 1, padding=1),
            nn.PReLU(256),

            nn.Conv3d(256, 256, 3, 1, padding=1),
            nn.PReLU(256),

            nn.Conv3d(256, 256, 3, 1, padding=1),
            nn.PReLU(256),
        )

        self.decoder_stage2 = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Conv3d(128 + 64, 128, 3, 1, padding=1),
            nn.PReLU(128),

            nn.Conv3d(128, 128, 3, 1, padding=1),
            nn.PReLU(128),

            nn.Conv3d(128, 128, 3, 1, padding=1),
            nn.PReLU(128),
        )

        self.decoder_stage3 = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Conv3d(64 + 32, 64, 3, 1, padding=1),
            nn.PReLU(64),

            nn.Conv3d(64, 64, 3, 1, padding=1),
            nn.PReLU(64),

            nn.Conv3d(64, 64, 3, 1, padding=1),
            nn.PReLU(64),
        )

        self.decoder_stage4 = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Conv3d(32 + 16, 32, 3, 1, padding=1),
            nn.PReLU(32),

            nn.Conv3d(32, 32, 3, 1, padding=1),
            nn.PReLU(32),
        )

        self.down_conv1 = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Conv3d(16, 32, 2, 2),
            nn.PReLU(32)
        )

        self.down_conv2 = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Conv3d(32, 64, 2, 2),
            nn.PReLU(64)
        )

        self.down_conv3 = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Conv3d(64, 128, 2, 2),
            nn.PReLU(128)
        )

        self.down_conv4 = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Conv3d(128, 256, 3, 1, padding=1),
            nn.PReLU(256)
        )

        self.up_conv2 = nn.Sequential(
            nn.ConvTranspose3d(256, 128, 2, 2),
            nn.PReLU(128)
        )

        self.up_conv3 = nn.Sequential(
            nn.ConvTranspose3d(128, 64, 2, 2),
            nn.PReLU(64)
        )

        self.up_conv4 = nn.Sequential(
            nn.ConvTranspose3d(64, 32, 2, 2),
            nn.PReLU(32)
        )
        
        # 256*256
        self.map4 = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Conv3d(32, out_channel, 1, 1),
            nn.Upsample(scale_factor=(1, 1, 1), mode='trilinear', align_corners=False),
            nn.Softmax(dim=1)
        )

        # 128*128 
        self.map3 = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Conv3d(64, out_channel, 1, 1),
            nn.Upsample(scale_factor=(2, 2, 2), mode='trilinear', align_corners=False),
            nn.Softmax(dim=1)
        )

        # 64*64 
        self.map2 = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Conv3d(128, out_channel, 1, 1),
            nn.Upsample(scale_factor=(4, 4, 4), mode='trilinear', align_corners=False),

            nn.Softmax(dim=1)
        )

        # 32*32 
        self.map1 = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Conv3d(256, out_channel, 1, 1),
            nn.Upsample(scale_factor=(8, 8, 8), mode='trilinear', align_corners=False),
            nn.Softmax(dim=1)
        )

    def forward(self, inputs):

        long_range1 = self.encoder_stage1(inputs) + inputs

        short_range1 = self.down_conv1(long_range1)

        long_range2 = self.encoder_stage2(short_range1) + short_range1
        long_range2 = F.dropout(long_range2, self.dorp_rate, self.training)

        short_range2 = self.down_conv2(long_range2)

        long_range3 = self.encoder_stage3(short_range2) + short_range2
        long_range3 = F.dropout(long_range3, self.dorp_rate, self.training)

        short_range3 = self.down_conv3(long_range3)

        long_range4 = self.encoder_stage4(short_range3) + short_range3
        long_range4 = F.dropout(long_range4, self.dorp_rate, self.training)

        short_range4 = self.down_conv4(long_range4)

        outputs = self.decoder_stage1(long_range4) + short_range4
        outputs = F.dropout(outputs, self.dorp_rate, self.training)

        output1 = self.map1(outputs)

        short_range6 = self.up_conv2(outputs)

        outputs = self.decoder_stage2(torch.cat([short_range6, long_range3], dim=1)) + short_range6
        outputs = F.dropout(outputs, self.dorp_rate, self.training)

        output2 = self.map2(outputs)

        short_range7 = self.up_conv3(outputs)

        outputs = self.decoder_stage3(torch.cat([short_range7, long_range2], dim=1)) + short_range7
        outputs = F.dropout(outputs, self.dorp_rate, self.training)

        output3 = self.map3(outputs)

        short_range8 = self.up_conv4(outputs)

        outputs = self.decoder_stage4(torch.cat([short_range8, long_range1], dim=1)) + short_range8

        output4 = self.map4(outputs)

        if self.training is True:
            return output1, output2, output3, output4
        else:
            return output4```
````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pad your image's dimensions to be multiple of 32's. By doing this, you won't have to change the 3DUnet's parameters.

I will provide you a simple code to show you the way.

```
# I assume that you named your input image as img

padding1_mult = math.floor(img.shape[3] / 32) + 1
padding2_mult = math.floor(img.shape[4] / 32) + 1
pad1 = (32 * padding1_mult) - img.shape[3]
pad2 = (32 * padding2_mult) - img.shape[4] 

padding = nn.ReplicationPad2d((0, pad2, pad1, 0, 0 ,0))

img = padding(img)
```

After this operation, your image shape must be `torch.Size([1, 1, 96, 192, 192])`

Comment: Hi, @hus, thank you for the reply, that really helps! This can solve my problem by padding the dimensions to be multiple of 32's. But later I found it exceeds my GPU memory, may I ask if there are any practical methods that we can resize the image to [1, 1, 96, 128, 128] instead of torch.Size([1, 1, 96, 192, 192])?

Comment: You can interpolate your image to the exact size that you want using interpolation function provided by PyTorch. You can find the related document in https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.functional.interpolate.html website. I suggest you to carefully read the explanations in the docs to get a better result. By the way, I do not suggest you to interpolate your image to bigger size since it is going to estimate the missing features.